# How can i change the color of Gridlines of Extended WPF propertygrid

Tags: propertygrid

I am using WPF extended Propertygrid i have change the background color of propertygrid but i am unable to change the color of gridlines and the white are of propertygrid. please see the image at the below mentioned link.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5865812/image1.png

Thanks,

Comment: Please share what you've tried, and please try to embed the image rather than an external link.

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy one. There is no easy "Style" property to configure the ItemsControl inside the PropertyGrid. You can copy the entire template of the PropertyGrid from the source and modify it.

You should ask for a feature request on the issue tracker on codeplex.

In the meantime, the way I found is by creating your own subclass of PropertyGrid, and force a GroupStyle in the underlying template part:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
  base.OnApplyTemplate();
  PropertyItemsControl control = ( PropertyItemsControl )this.GetTemplateChild( "PART_PropertyItemsControl" );
  var s = ( GroupStyle )this.Resources[ "groupStyle" ];
  control.GroupStyle.RemoveAt( 0 );
  control.GroupStyle.Add( s );
}
```

And in your xaml:

```
      <local:MyPropertyGrid >
     <local:MyPropertyGrid.Resources>
        <GroupStyle x:Key="groupStyle">
           <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                 <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate>
                          <Border>
                             <Expander Header="{Binding Name}"
                                       IsExpanded="True"
                                       Background="Green">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                             </Expander>
                          </Border>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
              </Style>
           </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
     </local:MyPropertyGrid.Resources>
      </local:MyPropertyGrid >
```